Chrome Extension + React + Vite Build in different folders
I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension with react and vite.
I have an App within the main folder "src" main.jsx and App.jsx. But i want another jsx file in a subfolder to be build in the same subfolder in the "dist" folder.

src

main.jsx, App.jsx
subfolder with navbar.jsx


public

But everything i tried with the vise.config.js does not show up the result i want. Either the content folder is not build or has stuff from the public folder in it, or only the navbar.jsx is build.... The example misses the content folder. I tried some rollipOptions which do not work well.
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
base: "",
plugins: [react()],
resolve: {
  alias: {
    "@": path.resolve(path.resolve(), "src"),
  },
},
});


Google prohibits the use of code obfuscation. I am not sure if this will pass the review.
